# Can't post links in Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I noticed I can't post links with preview. The post button looks kinda grey and I can't press it.

But I can share links without any preview.

I tried on my brother's account and the problem persists.

It was working perfectly fine this morning and this evening it's not.

---

Question: Is there a fix? Is anyone else having the same trouble? I tried resetting the browser, no effect.